# Filemaker 10 Intermittent Client Errors -1728

Tags: applescript, filemaker

All,

On one of our Filemaker Server 10 database applications, a client user has been getting intermittent -1728 errors when running a script, attached to a button:

**Unkown Error: -1728**

[image]

Based on what I've learned from the user, the -1728 error happens right before a "show layout" command. (see below). I am suspecting the "set theInventoryID" command  that executes right before the error:

```
set theDatabaseName to "F&B POs"
set theCellName to "Product ID"
tell application "FileMaker Pro"

  set theInventoryID to contents of cell "ID" of current record
  tell database theDatabaseName
  --  -1728 error happens here!!

  show layout "Inventory - All Quantities"
  show every record
  ...
```

What's the best practice in FM to bullet-proof against that?

Something like?

```
tell application "FileMaker Pro"
 try
  set theInventoryID to contents of cell "ID" of current record
  on error
    display dialog ("Make sure all inventory ids are valid")
 end try

tell database theDatabaseName
--  -1728 error happens here
show layout "Inventory - All Quantities"
show every record
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's an AppleScript error "Can't get (something)". Make sure all the layouts and fields exist. Also, if an AppleScript is run from within FileMaker, it doesn't need `tell application "FileMaker Pro"/end tell` block, as it's already telling the application.